# Jesus Christ was concealed in Old Testament why?

Tags: greek, word-study, new-world-translation

Jesus in the Old Testament was concealed for a reason, but then the New Testament makes him known.

Please explain to me, with scriptural backing, why GOD could only bring forth the manifested Christ at the time of the New Testament. Why did mankind have to wait?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Unfortunately this question is off-topic here as it is not about the interpretation of a specific part of the Bible.

Answer (score 2):

Life was not concealed at all. The tree of Life was in the very midst of the garden of Eden. And God specifically warned the first man on earth that the tree of knowledge of good and evil was not how humanity lived. It would prove fatal, if that tree were chosen as a means of obtaining and sustaining Life.

In the Logos was Life (John 1:4) and that Life was the Light of men.

God spoke in Eden and that (God's revealing himself, in word) was the tree of Life. Hear and your shall live.

Life was there, in the midst of the garden. And Life was passed by in favour of a way of man's independence from God and man's works on his own behalf and man's righteousness rather than God's rightness.

Right from the very beginning there was full disclosure, full revelation suitable to the circumstances and suitable to the relevant maturity of humanity at the time (in terms of understanding).

And some heeded what was given : Adam (eventually) then Abel then Enoch then Noah.

Every detail of the ark which Noah was instructed to make is full - absolutely full - of spiritual meaning and spiritual guidance and spiritual revelation. Every single detail.

Then Job speaks of a Redeemer. Then the God of glory appeared to Abraham. Then three men (yes three) come to Abraham and Abraham says, 'lord'.

Then a man wrestles with Jacob and declines to give his name.

Then a messenger visits the wife of Manoah and declines to give his name. And goes up in the flame of the sacrifice to heaven.

Then the messenger of Jehovah appears in a self-sustaining flame (associated with a bush) and Jehovah sees Moses turn aside and Elohim called unto Moses out of the midst.

Then a fourth is seen in the furnace when only three went in and none of them is harmed and the Gentile King, the highest natural authority on earth at the time says

> the form of the fourth is like the Son of God ! [Daniel 3:25, KJV.]

---

"Concealed" ?

Or rather is it not the case that :

> In him was Life and the Life was the light of men. And the light shineth in darkness and the darkness comprehended it not. [John 1:5, KJV.]

For very righteous reasons there was a progressive revelation of the purposes of God. The first creation was never the ultimate purpose. But righteousness required that the first man should be treated properly.

Only after due time and due treatment of the first humanity, in Adam, was all revealed in another humanity, a last Adam and a second man - the Lord from heaven. I Corinthians 15:45-47.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is loaded with assumptions (good ones!) but they should be established first.

1. **Jesus Christ is revealed in the Old Testament**. We know this, because Jesus said so, when he was walking with two men to Emmaus:

> 25 He said to them, “How foolish you are, and how slow to believe all
>   that the prophets have spoken! 26 Did not the Messiah have to suffer
>   these things and then enter his glory?” 27 And beginning with Moses
>   and all the Prophets, he explained to them what was said in all the
>   Scriptures concerning himself. *(Luke 24:25-27)*

2. **This revelation of Jesus is concealed**. This is apparent in the previous words and confusion of the two men in Luke, but also stated here by Paul in Ephesians:

> 2 Surely you have heard about the administration of God’s grace that
>   was given to me for you, 3 that is, the **mystery** made known to me by
>   revelation, as I have already written briefly. 4 In reading this,
>   then, you will be able to understand my insight into the **mystery** of
>   Christ, 5 **which was not made known to people in other generations** as
>   it has now been revealed by the Spirit to God’s holy apostles and
>   prophets. 6 This **mystery** is that through the gospel the Gentiles are
>   heirs together with Israel, members together of one body, and sharers
>   together in the promise in Christ Jesus.
>
> 7 I became a servant of this gospel by the gift of God’s grace given
>   me through the working of his power. 8 Although I am less than the
>   least of all the Lord’s people, this grace was given me: to preach to
>   the Gentiles the boundless riches of Christ, 9 and to make plain to
>   everyone the administration of this **mystery**, **which for ages past was
>   kept hidden in God**, who created all things. *(Ephesians 3:2-7)*

3. **This concealment serves a purpose.** Paul lets us know that it is an eternal purpose.

> 10 His intent was that now, through the church, the manifold wisdom of
>   God should be made known to the rulers and authorities in the heavenly
>   realms, 11 according to his eternal purpose that he accomplished in
>   Christ Jesus our Lord. 12 In him and through faith in him we may
>   approach God with freedom and confidence. *(Ephesians 3:10-12)*

4. **The concealment was intentional and originated in God's actions, not ours.**

Thus, continuing with Ephesian 3, though it is true that we are sinners who by our sin blind our hearts to the truth and glory or God, the plan of concealment preceded our sin. We are not the original cause of the concealment; God's plan was.

5. **Scripture explains some elements of that purpose**: the formation of the image of Christ within the believer.

> 24 Now I rejoice in what I am suffering for you, and I fill up in my
>   flesh what is still lacking in regard to Christ’s afflictions, for the
>   sake of his body, which is the church. 25 I have become its servant by
>   the commission God gave me to present to you the word of God in its
>   fullness— 26 the mystery that has been kept hidden for ages and
>   generations, but is now disclosed to the Lord’s people. 27 To them God
>   has chosen to make known among the Gentiles the glorious riches of
>   **this mystery, which is Christ in you, the hope of glory**. *(Colossians
>   1:24-27)*

6. **A crucial aspect of God's concealment was that the revelation is the grand work of Israel and the Church**:

> 10 Concerning this salvation, **the prophets**, who spoke of the grace
>   that was to come to you, **searched intently and with the greatest care**,
>   11 **trying to find out the time and circumstances to which the Spirit
>   of Christ in them was pointing when he predicted the sufferings of the
>   Messiah and the glories that would follow**. 12 It was revealed to them
>   that they were not serving themselves but you, when they spoke of the
>   things that have now been told you by those who have preached the
>   gospel to you by the Holy Spirit sent from heaven. Even angels long to
>   look into these things. *(1 Peter 1:10-12)*

If full knowledge of Christ were available before he arrived, the prophets would have nothing to do!

> It is the glory of God to conceal a matter;
>       to search out a matter is the glory of kings. *(Proverbs 25:2)*

7. **God's purpose is tied up with the experience of suffering in this world.** Ignorance, the seeming purposelessness of life and suffering, these create the ground upon which faith is revealed by its contrast. When the Old Testament believer walked in faith and demonstrated Christ-likeness and Christ-consciousness despite ignorance of who Christ was or what he planned to do, it is a proof of God's power and the ministry of the Holy Spirit:

> 8 The wind blows wherever it pleases. You hear its sound, but you
>   cannot tell where it comes from or where it is going. So it is with
>   everyone born of the Spirit.” (John 3:8)

If you study Job, you will see that in the midst of suffering, ignorance, blindness, and confusion, a man who said he could not see God at the same time spoke words that prophesied the coming savior. In fact, I found nine specific prophesies spoken by Job that point to elements of Jesus' ministry, and those elements are listed in the chronological order in which they occurred in Jesus' life!

Thus the requirement for deep understanding of God's purposes, especially as they relate to the revelation of Jesus, is that a righteous person endure great suffering without abandoning faith in God. There are not many people like that! That is why the greatest revelation had to be performed by Jesus, the perfectly righteous person who suffered the greatest amount. It is only through suffering that the message can be delivered. All the prophets suffered, and from their suffering, faith, and meditation on God's word, they obtained the insight that added to our knowledge of God and the Messiah.

8. **The message must pass from spoken word through a process of enscripturation in order to come to us in proper context with full assurance of its truth.**

Job was likely the first book of the Bible to be written. Prior to Jesus, Job was the most righteous person who ever lived, and he suffered greatly, hence he was a suitable vessel to communicate to us some teaching about Jesus. Job prayed that his words be written down - Job prayed the Bible into existence!

```
23 “Oh, that my words were recorded,
    that they were written on a scroll, 24 that they were inscribed with an iron tool on lead,
    or engraved in rock forever! 25 I know that my redeemer lives,
    and that in the end he will stand on the earth. 26 And after my skin has been destroyed,
    yet in my flesh I will see God; 27 I myself will see him
    with my own eyes—I, and not another.
    How my heart yearns within me! (Job 19:23-27)
```

Comment: I love your answer

Answer (score 0):

God is the Boss.  It is all his plan.

We don't necessarily have to accept or know God's reasons.  He is Sovereign.

In Acts chapter 1 when Jesus followers asked about when the kingdom of God would come, he said:

> "It is not for you to know the times of the seasons, which the Father hath put in his own power."  Acts 1:7 KJV

In the parable of the wedding banquet in Matthew 22, Jesus refers to the different people who were invited to the banquet (God's kingdom), but in verse 8 the king in the parable says the wedding is now ready.  This means that preparations were being made beforehand.

Similarly, preparations were being made in the Old Testament, and then when the time was ready, Elijah/John the Baptist started preparing the way (the hearts of people) to begin receiving Jesus Christ.

So in answer to the question, I believe that Jesus Christ wasn't directly revealed in the Old Testament because the Father was still making preparations for when he had planned to "officially" reveal Jesus Christ.  The Son could have come earlier, he always exists, but it was not part of the Father's plan to reveal him then.

Answer (score 0):

"**Jesus in the Old Testament was concealed for a reason, but then the New Testament makes him known.**"

You have the right idea, but completely backward.

The statement would be true if it said "The Father" rather than "Jesus".

## The Father was revealed in the New Testament:

- Matthew 11:27 "*All things have been delivered to Me by My Father, and no one knows the Son except the Father. Nor does anyone know the Father except the Son, and the one to whom **the Son wills to reveal Him**.*"
- John 1:18 "***No one has seen God at any time**. The only begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the Father, He has declared Him.*"
- John 5:37 "*And the Father Himself, who sent Me, has testified of Me. **You have neither heard His voice at any time, nor seen His form**.*"
- John 6:46 "***Not that anyone has seen the Father**, except He who is from God; He has seen the Father.*"
- John 17:25-26 "*O righteous Father! **The world has not known You**, but I have known You; and these have known that You sent Me. And I have declared to them Your name, and will declare it, that the love with which You loved Me may be in them, and I in them.*"

## Jesus was "YHWH", the God of the Old Testament:

- John 1:1-3,14 "*In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.
  He was in the beginning with God.
  … **All things were made through Him**, and without Him nothing was made that was made.And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we beheld His glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father, full of grace and truth.*"
- Ephesians 3:9 "*and to make all see what is the fellowship of the mystery, which from the beginning of the ages has been hidden in God who **created all things through Jesus Christ***"
- Colossians 1:16 "*For **by Him all things were created** that are in heaven and that are on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or principalities or powers. All things were created through Him and for Him.*"
- 1Corinthians 10:1-4 "*Moreover, brethren, I do not want you to be unaware that all our fathers were under the cloud, all passed through the sea,
  all were baptized into Moses in the cloud and in the sea,
  all ate the same spiritual food,
  and all drank the same spiritual drink. For they drank of that spiritual Rock that followed them, and **that Rock was Christ**.*"
- Compare Isaiah 44:6 with Revelation 2:8: "*… I am the First and I am the Last; Besides Me there is no God.*" with "*… These things says the **First and the Last**, who was dead, and came to life*"
- Compare Exodus 3:14 with John 8:57-59: "*And God said to Moses, “I AM WHO I AM.” And He said, “Thus you shall say to the children of Israel, ‘I AM has sent me to you.’ ”*" with "*Then the Jews said to Him, “You are not yet fifty years old, and have You seen Abraham?” with "*Jesus said to them, “Most assuredly, I say to you, before Abraham was, **I AM**.” Then they took up stones to throw at Him; but Jesus hid Himself and went out of the temple, going through the midst of them, and so passed by.*"

In the last incident, note that Jesus's listeners understood what he meant; they were going to stone him for blasphemy, claiming to **be the God of the Old Testament**.

Answer (score -1):

Declare ye, and bring near, Yea, they take counsel together, Who hath proclaimed this from of old? From that time hath declared it? Is it not I — Jehovah? And there is no other god besides Me, A God righteous and saving, there is none save Me.

Turn to Me, and be saved, all ends of the earth, For I [am] God, and there is none else.

By Myself I have sworn, Gone out from my mouth **the logos of justice**, And it turneth not back, That to Me, bow doth every knee, every tongue swear.

Only in Jehovah, said hath one, Have I righteousness and strength, Unto Him he cometh in, And ashamed are all those displeased with Him.

In Jehovah are all the seed of Israel justified, And they boast themselves.’  Isaiah 45:21-25

The origin of Johannine terminology. Jesus is the tabernaculate logos in the flesh. The manifestation of God in Cloud.

Comment: Ok.

The beginning of the Logos is the Truth. Psalms 118(119 HEB). 60,
The Logos is True. 2 Timothy 2:15
The True Logos is the Gospel. Ephesians 1:13,
The Logos became flesh. John 1:14,
The Logos of God is the Truth. John 17:17,
The True Logos is a means of generation. James 1:18
The Logos of God is within the begotten. 1 John 2:14,
The Logos of God is the Seed of God. Luke 8:11.

Comment: ok. I do not confuse logos with Jesus in the OT. Jesus did not exist, the Son does. The Son is the Logos of Truth. Jesus existing with the tabernacle.

Comment: Go ahead and edit your answer vs. adjust/explain it through comments. Thanks.

Comment: I believe at least from Isaiah 45:23 the "spoken" word is in view and can be confirmed by the statement, ""The word has gone forth from My mouth in righteousness And will not turn back. Isaiah 45:19 also confirms this when it says, "I have not spoken in secret." Moreover, since this is about Jesus in the OT who is apparently concealed, well I don't buy it. He was all over the OT as prophesied  as the coming Messiah. Now, the first five words of Isaiah 45:23 are, "I have sworn by Myself." The same words appear at Genesis  22:16 as "By Myself I have sworn." Who swore them at Genesis  22:15?