# Who is coming Christ or Yahweh in Zechariah 14:5?

Tags: jesus, zechariah, second-coming

Zechariah 14:5 (NIV)

> You will flee by my mountain valley, for it will extend to Azel. You will flee as you fled from the earthquake in the days of Uzziah king of Judah. Then the LORD my God will come, and all the holy ones with him.

I understand LORD replaces YHWH sometimes translated Yahweh or Jehovah

My question is: Is this passage referring to the second coming? If it is, who is coming Christ or Yahweh?

Comment: "*I understand LORD replaces YHWH sometimes translated Yahweh or Jehovah*".  See my answer to [What is the difference between LORD and GOD? - Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71062/what-is-the-difference-between-lord-and-god/71065#71065).

Answer (score 5):

The short answer to "*who is coming Christ or Yahweh?*" is "yes, he is".
Christ and Yahweh were actually the same being.

See my answer to [contradiction - How can John 1:18 say that "No man has seen God" when the Bible says that Abraham, Moses, Job and others have? - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44536/how-can-john-118-say-that-no-man-has-seen-god-when-the-bible-says-that-abraha/44559#44559).

Answer (score 3):

The prophet Zechariah foretold of the coming of the LORD God, an event which would take place at the Mount of Olives:

> On that day, He will set His feet on the Mount of Olives, near Jerusalem on the east; and the Mount of olives shall split across from east to west, and one part of the Mount shall shift to the north and the other part to the south, a huge gorge. And the valley in the Hills shall be shall be stopped up, for the Valley of the Hills shall reach to Azal; it shall be stopped up as it was stopped up as a result of an earthquake in the days of King Uzziah of Judah. - And the LORD my God, with all the holy beings, will come to you. (Zechariah 14:4-5 NJPS)

The heavenly witnesses to Jesus ascending into heaven told the disciples He would return:

> <sup>6</sup> So when they had come together, they asked him, “Lord, will you at this time restore the kingdom to Israel?” <sup>7</sup> He said to them, “It is not for you to know times or seasons that the Father has fixed by his own authority. <sup>8</sup> But you will receive power when the Holy Spirit has come upon you, and you will be my witnesses in Jerusalem and in all Judea and Samaria, and to the end of the earth.” <sup>9</sup> And when he had said these things, as they were looking on, he was lifted up, and a cloud took him out of their sight. <sup>10</sup> And while they were gazing into heaven as he went, behold, two men stood by them in white robes, <sup>11</sup> and said, “Men of Galilee, why do you stand looking into heaven? This Jesus, who was taken up from you into heaven, will come in the same way as you saw him go into heaven.” <sup>12</sup> Then they returned to Jerusalem from the mount called Olivet, which is near Jerusalem, a Sabbath day's journey away. (Acts 1 ESV)

Comment: Thank you are you saying Zechariah is referring to second coming

Answer (score 2):

Zechariah 14 speaks of the second coming of Jesus who is YHVH the Son.  Isaiah 48:12-16, Zechariah 2:6-11, Psalm 45 and others show that there are 2 beings that are referred to as YHVH yet they are one.  Jesus is referred to in terms that are exclusive to YHVH of the OT. First and Last, bridegroom, judge, our life, Rock, are a few.

Answer (score 0):

#### Who is coming Christ or Yahweh in Zechariah 14:5?

In the original Hebrew, the word used is *Yhvh* ([Strong's H3068](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/3068.htm)) which is the proper name of God, Yahweh or Jehovah as is mentioned in the question.

The [Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/jfb/zechariah/14.htm) gives the following for this verse:

> Lord my God … with thee—The mention of the "Lord my God" leads the prophet to pass suddenly to a direct address to Jehovah.

**Is this passage referring to the second coming?**
I personally have not seen this referring to the second coming. Though I would imagine that some could say that it does.

Answer (score -2):

Great question.  Love this as it is just one more supremely powerful yet often overlooked verse proving YHVH Father, Son and Holy Spirit being one in the same.

Beautiful..

To interpret God's word one must use his method of answering all questions by his own word elsewhere.  This verse is no different as it has many direct supporting Scripture as foundation of truth to lean on.

Yes it is God our Saviour and Lord Jesus Christ here yet again,  defined as one.

Take merely these of dozens of references as to their identical relationship..

"I am"..
"I am the Alpha and Omega, the first and the Last.". Both quotes attributed to God the Father and Son.  This passage you refer to is just one more and other NT Scripture clearly shows it is Jesus who comes.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Hi Bill, the approach you describe is actually the opposite of hermeneutics - *exegeting* a text is all about focusing on how the text itself was intended by its author or understood by its original recipients, *in its original context*. Only once we've understood what the text originally meant can we then compare and contrast it with later texts. This isn't the only way to study the scriptures, but it is the topic of this SE site. Hope that helps - do take the Site Tour as agarza linked above. Thanks again for contributing.